# Pandas Dataframe: delete rows with DateTime within 12 hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

For each IMEI, I would like to check whether any subsequent `DATETIME OF LVD` occurs within 12 hours. If they do, they need to be removed.

For example, in this df rows 1,6,13,14,15 would need to be removed.

```
               IMEI      DATETIME OF LVD  
0   864811031001402  2018-10-04 23:50:00         
1   864811031001402  2018-10-05 04:35:00         
2   864811031001402  2018-10-15 03:40:00       
3   864811031001402  2018-10-21 04:25:00        
4   866710038341548  2018-10-27 05:53:00       
5   864811031092336  2018-10-17 18:10:00         
6   864811031092336  2018-10-17 18:41:00       
7   864811031092336  2018-10-21 04:50:00          
8   864811031092336  2018-10-23 03:21:00         
9   864811031092336  2018-10-24 03:00:00        
10  864811031009041  2018-10-13 21:52:00       
11  864811031009041  2018-10-27 11:13:00       
12  864811031015584  2018-10-27 00:48:00        
13  864811031015584  2018-10-28 05:25:00        
14  864811031015584  2018-10-28 05:26:00        
15  864811031015584  2018-10-28 05:27:00
```

I can get the delta time difference for each record (below), but how do I do it for each IMEI group?

```
df['Delta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME OF LVD']).diff()

               IMEI      DATETIME OF LVD              Delta
0   864811031001402  2018-10-04 23:50:00                NaT
1   864811031001402  2018-10-05 04:35:00    0 days 04:45:00
2   864811031001402  2018-10-15 03:40:00    9 days 23:05:00
3   864811031001402  2018-10-21 04:25:00    6 days 00:45:00
4   866710038341548  2018-10-27 05:53:00    6 days 01:28:00
5   864811031092336  2018-10-17 18:10:00 -10 days +12:17:00
6   864811031092336  2018-10-17 18:41:00    0 days 00:31:00
7   864811031092336  2018-10-21 04:50:00    3 days 10:09:00
8   864811031092336  2018-10-23 03:21:00    1 days 22:31:00
9   864811031092336  2018-10-24 03:00:00    0 days 23:39:00
10  864811031009041  2018-10-13 21:52:00 -11 days +18:52:00
11  864811031009041  2018-10-27 11:13:00   13 days 13:21:00
12  864811031015584  2018-10-27 00:48:00  -1 days +13:35:00
13  864811031015584  2018-10-28 05:25:00    1 days 04:37:00
14  864811031015584  2018-10-28 05:26:00    0 days 00:01:00
15  864811031015584  2018-10-28 05:27:00    0 days 00:01:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and filter by[`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with 2 boolean masks - comparing with Timedelta chained with check missing rows by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df['DATETIME OF LVD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME OF LVD'])

s = df.groupby('IMEI')['DATETIME OF LVD'].diff()
df = df[(s > pd.Timedelta('12 hour')) | s.isna()]
print (df)
               IMEI     DATETIME OF LVD
0   864811031001402 2018-10-04 23:50:00
2   864811031001402 2018-10-15 03:40:00
3   864811031001402 2018-10-21 04:25:00
4   866710038341548 2018-10-27 05:53:00
5   864811031092336 2018-10-17 18:10:00
7   864811031092336 2018-10-21 04:50:00
8   864811031092336 2018-10-23 03:21:00
9   864811031092336 2018-10-24 03:00:00
10  864811031009041 2018-10-13 21:52:00
11  864811031009041 2018-10-27 11:13:00
12  864811031015584 2018-10-27 00:48:00
13  864811031015584 2018-10-28 05:25:00
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
0                 NaT
1     0 days 04:45:00
2     9 days 23:05:00
3     6 days 00:45:00
4                 NaT
5                 NaT
6     0 days 00:31:00
7     3 days 10:09:00
8     1 days 22:31:00
9     0 days 23:39:00
10                NaT
11   13 days 13:21:00
12                NaT
13    1 days 04:37:00
14    0 days 00:01:00
15    0 days 00:01:00
Name: DATETIME OF LVD, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a ValueError on the `s = ...diff()` ?

Comment: @wazzahenry - For me it working nice, but one idea - is possible sorting values before `s...diff()` by `df = df.sort_values(['IMEI','DATETIME OF LVD'])` ?